# Why do my Screen Sharing bookmarks not remember the username?

Tags: bookmarks, remote-desktop

I have multiple machines, A, B and C. On all these machines I have to users, X and Y. Y is a spare account I rarely use (mostly for troubleshooting my X-account).

I have a bunch of bookmarks/favourites for the Screen Sharing program in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.ScreenSharing/Data/Library/Application Support/Screen Sharing`, or so I thought. These bookmarks appear if I right click on Screen Sharing in the Dock - but EVERY time I select them the login details are prefilled with the Y account details, despite that the last time I used it I used the X account. I have tried editing the XML (the bookmarks are actually a textfile with XML) and changed the URL to something like `vnc://x@A.local` but it doesn't "stick" (or in fact, I think Screen Sharing duplicates/creates new bookmarks every time I do this. Currently I have more than 15 such bookmarks - for three computers).

Why does Screen Sharing prefill the wrong account every time I open one of these bookmarks/recent servers? How do I make it prefill the right account? Without duplicating the bookmarks, that is.